# Is there a more elegant and efficient way to write brainf*** style loops in Mathematica?

Tags: functional-style

I'm having some fun writing a brainf*** interpreter in Mathematica. See this [wiki article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brainfuck) for more info.  It works nicely but I'd like to find an elegant, preferably functional, way to handle the looping structures.

This is a simple example of what I'm hoping to do with the solution I currently have in place. The variable `ptr` is the position of a pointer in the program. The variable `paren` is used to keep track of the brackets, it increments on "[" and decrements on "]" so it should be zero when I find the proper closing bracket.

```
ptr = 1;
paren = 1;
lst = {"[", "[", "-", "]", ">", ">", ">", ".", "<", "<", "<", "]", 
        ">", ">", ">", ">", ">", ">", "."};

While[paren > 0, ptr++; 
     Switch[lst[[ptr]], "[", paren++, "]", paren--, _, Null]]
```

Which tells me the closing "]" is located at position 12 in `lst`.

```
In[287]:= ptr

Out[287]= 12
```

Is there a more elegant and/or efficient way to do this?

Comment: +1, for digging up an obscure programming language to get an interpreted language to interpret.

Comment: If you get it working, you could set up BF cells in mma and use [WReach's method](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5451304/198315) to have it automatically interpreted.

Comment: @rcollyer I can see my productivity sliding far downhill on this one. Endless fun :)

Comment: Are you trying to make this a one pass interpreter?

Comment: You guys don't know Brainfuck? Well then, here's the single most amazing program I've ever seen: http://awib.googlecode.com/svn/builds/awib-0.3.b (Brainfuck compiler polyglot in Brainfuck, Bash, TCL and C. Oh, and the documentation is part of the source code. And it compiles to Linux executables, TCL, Ruby, Go and C code.)

Comment: Would it be cheating to just use the Brainf*** -> C conversion table in the Wiki (using Mathematica constructs such as While[...] rather than C constructs such as while (...) {...}). Then you could just call ToExpression.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

My solution isn't precisely what was asked for: it is the complete parser. At the moment, it is strictly a parser, but the functionality is all ready to be added.

```
Clear[bfinterpreter, bfeval, movf, movb, add1,  sub1, write, read, loop, 
      stored, loopdepth, rls]
rls = {">" -> movf, "<" -> movb, "+" -> add1, 
       "-" -> sub1, "." -> write, "," -> read,
       "]" :> With[{mode = loopdepth--}, loop[stored[mode]]]
  };

bfeval[a : (">" | "<" | "+" | "-" | "." | "," | "]")] := 
  With[{val = a /. rls}, 
   If[loopdepth == 0, 
    val[ptr], 
    AppendTo[stored[loopdepth], val]; ## &[]] 
  ]

bfeval["["] := (stored[++loopdepth] = {}; ## &[])
bfeval[_] := (## &[])

bfinterpreter[code_String] := 
  Block[{loopdepth = 0, stored, ptr, 
         movf, movb, add1,  sub1, write, read}, 
   bfeval /@ StringSplit[code, ""]
  ];
```

A user would access this by passing `bfinterpreter` as `String` of BF commands.  The string is split into individual characters via `StringSplit[code, ""]`, and then `bfeval` is mapped over the resulting list. `Scan` would be better for the full implementation, but I used `Map` here to show that the parser works. In particular, using this on the OPs supplied BF code we get

```
(* spaces added for demo purposes *)
bfinterpreter["[[-]>> > . <<<]>>>  >>>."]
(*
=> {loop[{          (* [ *)
      loop[{sub1}], (* [-] *)
      movf, (* > *)
      movf, (* > *)
      movf, (* > *) 
      write, (* . *) 
      movb, (* < *) 
      movb, (* < *) 
      movb  (* < *)
     }               
    ][ptr],    (* ] *)
    movf[ptr], (* > *) 
    movf[ptr], (* > *) 
    movf[ptr], (* > *) 
    movf[ptr], (* > *) 
    movf[ptr], (* > *) 
    movf[ptr], (* > *) 
    write[ptr] (* . *)
   }
*)
```

As you've probably figured out, all the magic happens in `bfeval`. The first form accepts all BF characters `{">", "<", "+", "-", ".", ",", "]"}`, but the open loop, "[". It works by applying a list of replacement rules to the supplied character and either storing it, if we're within a loop, or evaluating it immediately. The close loop rule, though, has added functionality in that it needs to both reduce loop counter, `loopdepth`, and return the stored commands for the loop, hence the use of `RuleDelayed` (`:>`).

The second form of `bfeval` simply increments the loop counter, and returns `##&[]` to ensure the final list doesn't contain `Null`s. And, the final form is the catch all for every other type of character.

Comment: wow, now I really understand your question about single versus multiple passes.  This setup will allow the code to be optimized on the fly in a way I can't in a single pass.  Very nice!

Comment: @Andy It still is a single pass interpreter because if you define `movf`, etc, they will be executed immediately. (This was also the comment about using `Scan`.) The loops had to be constructed outside of the normal execution order, so that they could be used effectively. But, you are correct, if you do not define the operations before executing `bfinterpreter` you can then optimize it in subsequent passes.

Comment: right, but one wouldn't have to define movf. I commented since the results you show make it obvious what a second pass might do for example, say I have ... add1, add1, add1,... If these are just inert and don't actually do anything, I could go back in a second pass and create add[3,ptr].

Comment: @Andy, that was exactly my thought when I asked the question.

Comment: I've accepted this answer because of the effort involved and because it caused me to rethink the way I'm approaching the problem in the first place.

Comment: rcollyer why not use `a : (">" | "<" | "+" | "-" | "." | "," | "]")`?  If I see more opportunities for streamlining such as this may I make the edit, or are you intentionally making things complicated?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I opted for `MemberQ` as it seemed more clear what I was attempting at the time. Similarly, I considered replacing the `With` statement in `bfeval` with a pure function operating on `a/.rls` directly, but with the `##&[]` present, I considered the named variable to be more clear.

Comment: Okay.  BTW, surely I like `##&[]` as I believe I am the one who popularized it on SE, but for reference you can use `Sequence[]` on the RHS of `:=` (I mean the bare use, not in CompoundExpression).

Comment: @Mr.Wizard true, as both `Set` and `SetDelayed` have the attribute [`SequenceHold`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/SequenceHold.html), but `CompoundExpression` does not. I think keeping `##&[]` works for consistency sake.

Comment: Agreed.  I just thought it was worth mentioning.

Comment: @AndyRoss I'm upgrading my gcc installation, and I ran across a recent addition to the available optimizations: [the polytope model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polytope_model). It is not in the newer versions by default, but surely you could implement something like this for the BF parser/interpreter ... :)

Answer (score 12):

Wasteful, but short and no side effects:

```
ReplaceList[lst, {x__, y___} /; Count[{x}, "["] == Count[{x}, "]"] :> Length[{x}], 1]
```

Comment: this is really neat and closest to the spirit of what I was shooting for thus far.

Answer (score 8):

This may be way off base as I really don't understand what you are doing, but perhaps something like:

```
Replace[lst, {"[" -> 1, "]" -> -1, _ -> 0}, 1];

Position[Accumulate@%, 0, 1, 1]
```

> {{12}}

Or perhaps:

```
paren = 0;
x@"[" := ++paren;
x@"]" := --paren;
1 + LengthWhile[x /@ lst, # =!= 0 &]
```

> 12

Perhaps more cryptically:

```
Position[
  Accumulate@lst,
  _?(Equal @@ # ~Coefficient~ {"[", "]"} &),
 {1}, 2
][[2]]
```

> {12}

Comment: @Andy I just added another one.  Is this closer to or farther from what you want?

Comment: I especially like that last one, very sneaky :)

Comment: `Accumulate@lst`??? Talk about misusing mma... +1

Answer (score 4):

I'd have done something like

```
ptr = paren = 0;
lst = {"[", "[", "-", "]", ">", ">", ">", ".", "<", "<", "<", "]", 
       ">", ">", ">", ">", ">", ">", "."};

res = 0;
Scan[(++ptr; Switch[#, "[", ++paren, "]", --paren; res = ptr, _, Null]) &, lst];
{paren, res}
```

myself.

---

A more compact version might go something like

```
Catch[Scan[(++ptr; Switch[#,
                          "[", ++paren,
                          "]", If[(--paren) == 0, Throw[ptr]],
                           _, Null]) &, lst]]
```

---

What follows is a `MapIndexed[]` version. I prefer the `Scan[]` versions myself, but at least `ptr` is no longer needed:

```
Catch[MapIndexed[
  Switch[#1, "[", ++paren,
             "]", If[(--paren) == 0, Throw[First[#2]]],
              _, Null] &, lst]]
```

Comment: I like this solution, hence the +1, but I'm hoping for something a bit more functional and cryptic in the spirit of both BF and the clever functional capabilities of M.

Comment: Ah, so you want to avoid the use of the `ptr` and `paren` auxiliary variables, I presume? Too bad there does not seem to be an analog of `MapIndexed[]` for `Scan[]`...

Comment: It seems your dream has come true as there is now a `ScanIndexed` function, albeit in the `GeneralUtilities` package.