# Splitting up delimited data in lists

Tags: programming, list-manipulation

One task that I frequently find myself doing in Mathematica is splitting lists into lists of sublists, using specific elements to define the break-points. This is particularly useful with imported files which often have a structure like this:

```
section 1
a
b
c
section 2 
d
e 
f
```

Upon import, this turns into

```
{"section 1", "a", "b", "c", "section 2", "d", "e", "f"}
```

I'd like to split this into sublists at the strings that mark sections, like so:

```
{{"a", "b", "c"}, {"d", "e", "f"}}
```

Doing this with Mathematica's library functions is pretty awkward. First, you want a predicate that tells you where the delimiting elements are:

```
delimiterQ[s_String] := StringMatchQ[s, "section "~~__]
delimiterQ[_]        := False
```

In cases like this, rule replacement seems like an elegant solution:

```
In[1]:= delimitingRule = {before___, _?delimiterQ, 
          Longest[run : Except[_?delimiterQ] ...], 
          after___} :> {before, {run}, after};
        {"section 1", "a", "b", "c", "section 2", "d", "e", "f"} //. delimitingRule
Out[1]= {{"a", "b", "c"}, {"d", "e", "f"}}
```

However, the performance of this kind of solution is truly atrocious, as you might expect (I got bored of waiting with a test list of 1000 elements after a couple minutes). The alternative I usually use is:

```
In[2]:= splitAtDelimiters[l_List, test_] :=
         With[{delimIndices = Flatten@Position[l, _?test, {1}], 
          len = Length@l},
          With[{first = First@delimIndices, last = Last@delimIndices},
           Take[l, #] & /@ Join[
             If[1 < first, {{1, first - 1}}, {}],
             # + {1, -1} & /@ Partition[delimIndices, 2, 1],
             If[last < len, {{last + 1, len}}, {}]]]];
In[3]:= splitAtDelimiters[
         {"section 1", "a", "b", "c", "section 2", "d", "e", "f"}, 
         delimiterQ]
Out[3]= {{"a", "b", "c"}, {"d", "e", "f"}}
```

This works OK, but I always think there must be a better way to do things whenever I generate a list of indices into a list just to immediately extract them all again. That sort of round trip is a Mathematica "code smell", IMO, and in this particular case there's a lot of extra work done to deal with corner cases involving delimiters at the begining or end of the list.

Any other suggestions? I think that there must be a way to do it with `Split`, but after trying a few obvious things I'm not sure what it is.

**EDIT** to add: My approach using `Position` has an annoying bug in cases where you are interested in splitting a list of lists (which is common when processing, say, Excel imports). The corrected version requires use of the `Heads -> False` option for `Position`:

```
splitAtDelimiters[l_List, test_] :=
 With[{delimIndices = 
    Flatten@Position[l, _?test, {1}, Heads -> False], len = Length@l},
   With[{first = First@delimIndices, last = Last@delimIndices},
    Take[l, #] & /@ Join[
     If[1 < first, {{1, first - 1}}, {}],
     # + {1, -1} & /@ Partition[delimIndices, 2, 1],
     If[last < len, {{last + 1, len}}, {}]]]]
```

Bugs like this make me think my unease with this approach is justified.

**EDIT** the second: rcollyer suggested I move this from StackOverflow.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The first thing that comes to mind is:

```
list = {"section 1", "a", "b", "c", "section 2", "d", "e", "f"};

delimiterQ[s_String] := StringMatchQ[s, "section " ~~ __]
delimiterQ[_] := False

SplitBy[list, delimiterQ][[2 ;; ;; 2]]
```

> ```
> {{"a", "b", "c"}, {"d", "e", "f"}}
> ```

---

Szabolcs raised the concern that if the first element of `list` is not a delimiter this breaks.  If you know in advance that the first element is *not* a delimiter you can use `[[;; ;; 2]]` -- if it is uncertain you might use this rather ugly blob of code:

```
#[[If[delimiterQ@#[[1, 1]], 2, 1] ;; All ;; 2]] & @ SplitBy[list, delimiterQ]
```

---

If you can create a list of all separators another option would be using `Import`.  With your data in `splitdat.txt`:

```
Rest@Import["splitdat.txt", "Table", 
  "LineSeparators" -> {"section 1", "section 2"}, 
  "FieldSeparators" -> "\n"]
```

> ```
> {{"a", "b", "c"}, {"d", "e", "f"}}
> ```

Likewise `ReadList`, which is probably faster:

```
ReadList["splitdat.txt",
  Word,
  WordSeparators -> "\n",
  RecordLists -> True,
  RecordSeparators -> {"section 1", "section 2"}
]
```

Comment: This is perfect, and it leaves the option of keeping the delimiters should I need them (which I sometimes do).

Comment: @Pillsy okay, great!  But you should wait to Accept an answer until you have seen what everyone else has to offer. :-)

Comment: This `Split` approach won't work if the list does not start with a delimiter.

Comment: @Szabolcs if the list doesn't start with a delimiter just use `[[;; ;; 2]]` instead.  It is not hard to test if the list starts with a delimiter.

Comment: I think the `SplitBy` solution is superior as you may not know the number of `"LineSeparators"` or `RecordSeparators` present. It somewhat irks me that you can't pass something a little more dynamic to those like a `StringExpression` (e.g. `"section " ~~ __`) or a `RegularExpression` to allow for more variation in importing.

Comment: @rcollyer I agree that string patterns would be nice!

Comment: @rcollyer If you check my answer, `StringSplit` can use a `RegularExpression` as the splitting test.

Comment: @Eli already upvoted your answer, but my kvetch was about neither `Import`, `Read`, nor `ReadList` can make use of that functionality.

Comment: @rcollyer Wasn't fishing for upvotes, but thanks. If you check back over past questions here and on SO about importing, it's clear that MMA is pretty terrible in that regard. Hard to work with large datasets, etc, etc.

Comment: @Eli sorry if I seemed to imply that you were fishing for upvotes; I meant that I had already reviewed your answer. And, yes, mma is terrible in importing.

Answer (score 8):

If you import your sample file as text, then do a `StringSplit` you have more control:

```
test="section 1\na\nb\nc\nsection 2\nd\ne\nf"
Rest/@StringSplit@StringSplit[test, "section "]
```

This outputs `{{"a", "b", "c"}, {"d", "e", "f"}}`

**Edit** In a comment, rcollyer complained about the inability to use `RegularExpression`. Using this approach you can:

```
StringSplit@StringSplit[test, "section " ~~ RegularExpression["\\d"]]
```

which has the same output as above.

Comment: An excellent alternative.

Answer (score 7):

Here is a solution based on a combination of rules and recursion, but not very efficient (the inefficiency spotted by @Pillsy, see below for the explanation):

```
Clear[splitAtDelimeters];
splitAtDelimeters[l_List, test_] :=
  Module[{split, h},
    h[{}] := h[];
    h[h[x___], h[y___]] := h[x, y];
    split[ls_] :=
      First@ReplaceList[
         ls,
         {{x___, el_?test, y___} :> h[h[{x}], split[{y}]], x_List :> h[x]},
         1];
    List @@ split[l]];
```

For example:

```
list = {"section 1", "a", "b", "c", "section 2", "d", "e", "f"};

delimiterQ[s_String] := StringMatchQ[s, "section " ~~ __]
delimiterQ[_] := False

splitAtDelimeters[list,delimiterQ]

(*
  ==> {{a,b,c},{d,e,f}}
*)
```

**EDIT**

As rightly noted by @Pillsy, the above solution is still quadratic complexity in the size of the list. I missed this point initially, but this is clearly due to massive list/ sequence copying in patterns like

```
{x___, el_?test, y___} :> h[h[{x}], split[{y}]]
```

(`y` is the culprit here).

Here is a linear time solution, based entirely on linked lists:

```
Clear[splitAtDelimetersLL];
splitAtDelimetersLL[l_List, test_] :=
  Module[{split, ll, llist, hh},
    SetAttributes[{ll, hh}, HoldAllComplete];
    llist = Fold[ll[#2, #1] &, ll[], Reverse@l];
    split[acc_, ll[_?test, t_], r_] := split[hh[], t, ll[r, acc]];
    split[acc_, ll[h_, t_], r_] := split[hh[acc, h], t, r];
    split[acc_, ll[], r_] := ll[r, acc];
    Map[
      Flatten[#, Infinity, hh] /. {hh[] :> Sequence[], hh[x__] :> {x}} &,
      List @@ Flatten[split[hh[], llist, hh[]], Infinity, ll]
    ]
  ];
```

It may be somewhat less elegant, but it avoids excessive copying characteristic for the previous one. It also is tail-recursive, so it affects `$IterationLimit` rather than `$RecursionLimit`, which is good. This solution is just as efficient as the one based on `SplitBy`, proposed by @Mr.Wizard, at least for this predicate / problem.

Comment: Leonid, I realize I hold you to a higher standard, but what is the benefit of this over `SplitBy`?  Or are you showing how one can implement such a function himself?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I just think this is an interesting code pattern, based entirely on rules (and recursion) and still being efficient. I can imagine other cases when this can be useful and no simple function like `Split` or `SplitBy` will exist. For this particular case, I don't claim any superiority of my code. Also, the OP wished to have some rule-based solution for this, that was part of my motivation. So, yes, if you wish, this illustrates how to efficiently implement a version of `SplitBy` with only the replacement rules.

Comment: Good enough for me. +1

Comment: @Leonid This is more efficient than my rule-based solution, but it's still O(n^2). Using rule-replacement with sequence-based patterns in lists is really hard to do efficiently.

Comment: @Pillsy Actually, you are right, I was not careful enough. Please see my edit for a linear-time solution.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin Cool. I like that approach to unfolding the linked list in the last step.

Answer (score 6):

Inspired by [rcollyer's state machine answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/52/rcollyer), I realized that with a little change you can generate index pairs to pass to `Take`, as in my original solution. The advantage of doing things this way is that, with a little help from `Boole`, you can easily recast the state machine as something that works in `Compile`.

```
compiledIndexer =
 Compile[{{tests, _Integer, 1}},
  With[{n = Length@tests},
   Module[{
     j = 1,
     fill = 0,
     result = ConstantArray[0, {2*Count[tests, 0], 2}],
     state = tests[[1]]},
     Do[
      If[BitXor[tests[[i]], state] == 1,
       result[[++fill]] = {j, i - 1};
       state = tests[[i]];
       j = i],
     {i, 2, n}];
    result[[++fill]] = {j, n};
    Take[result, fill]]]];
```

The rest of the function is just a one-liner. Well, a two-liner, because `Compile` can't return a zero-length list, so you need to specially handle an empty list:

```
splitWithCompile[{}, _] = {};
splitWithCompile[list_List, test_] :=
 With[{tests = Boole[test /@ list]},
  Take[list, #] & /@ compiledIndexer[tests]]
```

On my machine, this goes about 50% slower than [Heike's `SplitBy` solution](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/2152/531), but that's using Mathematica's bytecode compiler. I don't have a C compiler on this machine, so I can't really take full advantage of the Mathematica 8 compiler.

Comment: Pretty cool, +1. I'd recommend to replace `ConstantArray` (which is not compilable), with `Table`.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin I tried that, and it didn't make a discernible difference in performance. It's just one external call, and there's no reason `ConstantArray` can't really fly here.

Comment: Agree - when it is not in a loop, there isn't much of a difference. I just like it when everything *inside Compile* is compiled, and usually bring pieces which can not be compiled outside of `Compile`, but this is a matter of personal preference :)

Answer (score 5):

This is a variation of Mr.Wizard's answer:

```
list = {"section 1", "a", "b", "c", "section 2", "d", "e", "f"};

delimiterQ[s_String] := StringMatchQ[s, "section " ~~ __]
delimiterQ[_] := False

Rest /@ Split[list, (Not[delimiterQ[#2]] &)]
```

Here, I'm specifying a test function to `Split` to decide where the list should be split. For a test function `test`, say, the list will be split between consecutive elements `e1` and `e2` if `test[e1, e2]` returns `False`. The next sublist will then start with `e2`. In this case the list will be split between `e1` and `e2` if `Not[delimiterQ[e2]] == False`, i.e. when `delimiterQ[e2] == True`.

Comment: To my surprise this appears to be *faster* than `SplitBy`. +1 !

Comment: This won't work correctly if the list doesn't start with a delimiter .

Comment: @Szabolcs I guess you could do something like `Split[list, (Not[delimiterQ[#2]] &)] /. a_String /; delimiterQ[a] :> Sequence[]` instead

Answer (score 3):

I know, late to the party, but after my [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1599/52) for the Brainf*** parser, I have been thinking in terms of state machines. In this case, each instance of the pattern `"section " ~~ __` signals a change in state from one section to the next, so it seems like a solution based upon [`Sow`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Sow.html) and [`Reap`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Reap.html) should be doable with a cached section delimiter, as follows

```
splitAtDelimeters[l_List, test_, out_:Rule]:=
Module[{del = ""},
 Reap[If[
      test@#,
      del = #,
      Sow[#, del]
      ] & /@ l, _, out][[2]]
 ]

 splitAtDelimeters[list, StringMatchQ[#, "section " ~~ __] &]
 (*
 {"section 1" -> {"a", "b", "c"}, "section 2" -> {"d", "e", "f"}}
 *)
```

Incidentally, this works "out of the box" for lists without a starting delimiter:

```
 splitAtDelimeters[Rest@list, StringMatchQ[#, "section " ~~ __] &]
 (*
 {"" -> {"a", "b", "c"}, "section 2" -> {"d", "e", "f"}}
 *)
```

**Edit**: As pointed out, the above code does not work for non-unique delimiters. An alternative is to track them separately, and recombine them at the end, as follows:

```
Clear[splitAtDelimeters2]
splitAtDelimeters2[l_List, test_, out_: Rule] :=
 Module[{del = {}, section = 1},
  Reap[If[test@#,
        del = {del, #}; section++,
        Sow[#, section]
        ] & /@ l, _, #2 &
     ][[2]] // MapThread[out, 
     With[{lstdels = Flatten[del], terms = #1},
      {If[Length@lstdels != Length@terms, {""}, {}]~Join~lstdels, 
       terms}]
     ] &
  ]

longList = Flatten@ConstantArray[list, {3}];
splitAtDelimeters[longList, StringMatchQ[#, "section " ~~ __] &]
(*
{"section 1" -> {"a", "b", "c"}, "section 2" -> {"d", "e", "f"}, 
 "section 1" -> {"a", "b", "c"}, "section 2" -> {"d", "e", "f"}, 
 "section 1" -> {"a", "b", "c"}, "section 2" -> {"d", "e", "f"}}
*)
```

Or, without a leading delimiter

```
splitAtDelimeters[Rest@longList, StringMatchQ[#, "section " ~~ __] &]
(*
{"" -> {"a", "b", "c"}, "section 2" -> {"d", "e", "f"}, 
 "section 1" -> {"a", "b", "c"}, "section 2" -> {"d", "e", "f"}, 
 "section 1" -> {"a", "b", "c"}, "section 2" -> {"d", "e", "f"}}
*)
```

This works by tagging each entry with a unique section number (`section`), and then using `MapThread` with the accumulated delimiters (`del`).  The `If` is in there to ensure that the list of delimiters has the same length as the number of terms which will occur if the leading section is missing a delimiter.

Comment: This won't work when some delimeters are repeated several times, like e.g. in `Flatten@ ConstantArray[list, {3}]`.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin you're right, I had assumed (incorrectly) that the delimiters would be unique.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin I added something that will work for non-unique delimiters.

Comment: @rcollyer Another trick for making the state machine work is to detect edges; this has the advantage that you can just use the value of test as your state.

Comment: @Pillsy that's what I did with the BF parser. Here, I thought I could do something a little simpler.

Comment: Great, now I can vote for it. +1.

Answer (score 2):

```
list = {"section 1", "a", "b", "c", "section 2", "d", "e", "f"}
```

In a sense it is good to retain `section` information, but it can be removed from the following alternatives, if required. The `Sequence*` functions are slow, so these must unfortunately be avoided for larger lists.

```
SequenceReplace[list, {s_String?(StringContainsQ["section"]), 
   h___String?(StringFreeQ["section"])} :> {s, h}]
```

> {{"section 1", "a", "b", "c"}, {"section 2", "d", "e", "f"}}

Using `:> {h}` as the replacement pattern will generate sublists without the `section` delimiters.

---

The `Split` and `SplitBy` answers have appeared on this page previously along with the `delimiter` debate. I am using the `StringFreeQ` function as a predicate for demo.

```
Split[list, StringFreeQ[#2, "section"] &]
```

> {{"section 1", "a", "b", "c"}, {"section 2", "d", "e", "f"}}

---

```
SplitBy[list, StringFreeQ[#1, "section"] &]
```

> {{"section 1"}, {"a", "b", "c"}, {"section 2"}, {"d", "e", "f"}}

which can be partitioned in twos if required.

---

```
SequenceSplit[list, {x_String /; StringMatchQ[x, "section*"]}]
```

> {{"a", "b", "c"}, {"d", "e", "f"}}

Answer (score 2):

```
list = {"section 1", "a", "b", "c", "section 2", "d", "e", "f"};
```

A slot-free combination of Syed's answers:

```
SplitBy[list, StringFreeQ @ "section"][[2 ;; ;; 2]]
```

{{"a", "b", "c"}, {"d", "e", "f"}}

Answer (score 2):

Using `SplitBy` and `Select`:

```
list = {"section 1", "a", "b", "c", "section 2", "d", "e", "f"};

Select[SplitBy[list, StringContainsQ[#, "section"] &], AllTrue[#, LetterQ] &]

(*{{"a", "b", "c"}, {"d", "e", "f"}}*)
```

Comment: +1, very nice, you can write this slot-free as `Select[AllTrue@LetterQ]@SplitBy[list, StringContainsQ@"section"]`