# Splitting a list by specifying section headers

Tags: list-manipulation, string-manipulation

I have a list of strings called `mylist`:

```
mylist = {"[a]", "a", "a", "[b]", "b", "b", "[ c ]", "c", "c"};
```

I would like to split `mylist` by "section headers."  Strings that begin with the character `[` are section headers in my application.  Thus, I would like to split `mylist` in such a way as to obtain this output:

```
{{"[a]", "a", "a"}, {"[b]", "b", "b"}, {"[ c ]", "c", "c"}}
```

(The `a`s, `b`s, and `c`s represent *any* characters; the string inside the section header does *not* necessarily match the strings that follow in that section.  Also, the number of strings in each section can vary.

I have tried:

```
SplitBy[mylist, StringMatchQ[#, "[" ~~ ___] &]
```

But this is not correct; I obtain:

```
{{"[a]"}, {"a", "a"}, {"[b]"}, {"b", "b"}, {"[ c ]"}, {"c", "c"}}
```

Likewise, using `Split` (since it applies the test function only to adjacent elements) does not work.  The command:

```
Split[mylist, StringMatchQ[#, "[" ~~ ___] &]
```

yields:

```
{{"[a]", "a"}, {"a"}, {"[b]", "b"}, {"b"}, {"[ c ]", "c"}, {"c"}}
```

Do you have any advice?  Thanks.

Comment: Vaguely related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2150/121

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Here's my suggestion:

```
mylist = {"[a]", "a", "a", "[b]", "b", "b", "[ c ]", "c", "c"};

Split[mylist, ! StringMatchQ[#2, "[*"] &]
```

and we get:

```
{{"[a]", "a", "a"}, {"[b]", "b", "b"}, {"[ c ]", "c", "c"}}
```

Comment: Looks like the right way to me. +1

Answer (score 9):

At the risk of being annoying, I will pitch the linked lists again. Here is the code using linked lists:

```
ClearAll[split];
split[{}] = {};
split[l_List] :=
  Reap[split[{}, Fold[{#2, #1} &, {}, Reverse@l]]][[2, 1]];

split[accum_, {h_, tail : {_?sectionQ, _} | {}}] :=
  split[Sow[Flatten[{accum, h}]]; {}, tail];

split[accum_, {h_, tail_}] := split[{accum, h}, tail];
```

The function `sectionQ` has been stolen from the answer of @rm-rf. The usage is

```
split[mylist]

(* {{[a],a,a},{[b],b,b},{[ c ],c,c}} *)
```

The advantages I see in using linked lists is that they allow one to produce solutions which are

- Easily generalizable to more complex problems
- Straightforward to implement
- Easy to argue about (in terms of algorithmic complexity etc)

They may not be the fastest though, so may not always be suitable for performance-critical applications.

Answer (score 7):

Here's one method, using a slightly modified example:

```
mylist = {"[a]", "a", "[b]", "b", "b", "b", "[ c ]", "c", "c"};

pos = Append[Flatten[Position[mylist,
             s_String /; StringMatchQ[s, "[" ~~ ___]]], Length[mylist] + 1]
   {1, 3, 7, 10}

Take[mylist, {#1, #2 - 1}] & @@@ Partition[pos, 2, 1]
   {{"[a]", "a"}, {"[b]", "b", "b", "b"}, {"[ c ]", "c", "c"}}
```

Answer (score 7):

Here's one approach using `FixedPoint` and `Replace`:

```
sectionQ := ! StringFreeQ[#, "["] &;
FixedPoint[
    Replace[#, {h___, sec_?sectionQ, Longest[x___?(! sectionQ@# &)], t___} :> {h, t, {sec, x}}] &, 
    mylist]

(* {{"[a]", "a", "a"}, {"[b]", "b", "b"}, {"[ c ]", "c", "c"}} *)
```

Comment: One can also define `sectionQ = StringMatchQ[#, "[" ~~ ___] &`, as in the question to allow for `[` occurring somewhere (except the first position) in the strings following the section headers.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an answer based on the solution of Murta that parses recursively a list based on different delimiters that can be patterns or string patterns. This can be useful for example to parse a debug output where loops are involved.

```
splitByPattern[l_List,p_?System`Dump`validStringExpressionQ]:=splitByPattern[l, _String?(StringMatchQ[#, p] &)];
splitByPattern[l_List,p_]:=Split[l,!MatchQ[#2,p]&];

splitByPatternFold[l_,{},True|False]:=l;
splitByPatternFold[l_,{p_},False]:=splitByPattern[l,p];
splitByPatternFold[l_,{p_},True]:=Join[{First@l},splitByPattern[Rest@l,p]];
splitByPatternFold[l_,{p_,rest__},False]:=splitByPatternFold[#,{rest},True]&/@splitByPattern[l,p];
splitByPatternFold[l_,{p_,rest__},True]:=Join[{First@l},splitByPatternFold[#,{rest},True]&/@splitByPattern[Rest@l,p]];
splitByPatternFold[l_List,patterns_List,hasHeader_:False]:=splitByPatternFold[l,patterns,hasHeader];
```

To access the split elements you can use this function

```
splitAccess[l_, indices_] :=
Module[{offsets = Table[1, {Length@indices}]},
   offsets[[1]] = 0;
   l[[Sequence @@ (indices + offsets)]]
]
```

Example

```
l={a, b, c, d, e, f, a, b, c, d, e, f};

x = splitByPatternFold[l,{a,b,c,d,e}]
> {{a,{b,{c,{d,{e,f}}}}},{a,{b,{c,{d,{e,f}}}}}}

splitAccess[x,{2,1}]
> {b, {c, {d, {e, f}}}}
```

The answer to the question would be written as

```
mylist={"[a]",a,"a","[b]",b,"b","[ c ]",c,"c"};
splitByPattern[mylist,"[*"]
```

Note that all elements don't need to be strings when giving a string pattern as argument.

Answer (score 2):

Here's my version based on Position.

```
mylist = {"[a]", "a", "a", "[b]", "b", "b", "[ c ]", "c", "c"};

split[lst_List, pat_String] := Module[{len, pos},
  len = Length[lst];
  pos = Partition[Flatten[{Position[lst, _String?(StringMatchQ[#, pat ~~ __] &)],len + 1}], 2, 1];
  lst[[#[[1]] ;; #[[2]] - 1]] & /@ pos]
```

usage

```
split[mylist, "["]
```

Out

{{"[a]", "a", "a"}, {"[b]", "b", "b"}, {"[ c ]", "c", "c"}}

Answer (score 0):

```
Split[mylist, StringFreeQ["["] @ #2 &]
```

> {{"[a]", "a", "a"}, {"[b]", "b", "b"}, {"[ c ]", "c", "c"}}

```
SequenceCases[mylist, a:{_?(!StringFreeQ[ "["]@#&),__?(StringFreeQ[ "["])}:> {a}]
```

> {{"[a]", "a", "a"}, {"[b]", "b", "b"}, {"[ c ]", "c", "c"}}

Answer (score 0):

```
Clear["Global`*"];

mylist = {"[a]", "a", "a", "[b]", "b", "b", "[ c ]", "c", "c"};
patt = StartOfString ~~ Whitespace ... ~~ "[" ~~ Whitespace ... ~~ _ ~~
    Whitespace ... ~~ "]" ~~ Whitespace ... ~~ EndOfString;
```

Testing:

```
StringMatchQ[patt] /@ mylist
```

> {True, False, False, True, False, False, True, False, False}

Finally:

```
Split[mylist, StringMatchQ[#1, patt] || StringFreeQ[#2, patt] &]
```

This solution is tolerant of any combination of (additionally) inserted whitespace around "[" and "]".

---

*Result*

> {{"[a]", "a", "a"}, {"[b]", "b", "b"}, {"[ c ]", "c", "c"}}