# Is Mathematica a Turing-complete language?

Tags: programming

Is Mathematica a Turing-complete language?  If so, how can that be proved? If not, why?

Comment: Wasn't a machine that could decide nothing more than whether  to go forwards or backwards on the tape it was reading, Turing complete?

Comment: Well [Rule 110](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_110) is Turing complete, and Mathematica can implement Rule 110, so... yes?

Comment: @Verbeia - job done then :)

Comment: In practical sense, if a language contains a loop/recursive construction, conditional branches and memory allocation/deallocation, then it is almost certain that it is Turing complete (of course, it is not a formal proof :)).

[What are practical guidelines for evaluating a language's “Turing Completeness”?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/449014/what-are-practical-guidelines-for-evaluating-a-languages-turing-completeness)

And of course Mathematica language is Turing complete.

Comment: @Yu-SungChang Not neccessarily. There are restrictions you can place on recursion that will not longer make it turing complete. The Coq programming language is an example of this.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It has already been proven that the  [Rule 110 cellular automata](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_110) is Turing complete. Since Mathematica can implement this cellular automata, it must be true that Mathematica is Turing complete.

Incidentally, it has been claimed that [HTML + CSS3 is Turing complete](http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=2300836), and Mathematica is a bit more expansive than that combination. So it should not be surprising that Mathematica is also Turing complete.

All this is with the standard limitation that a 'real' turing machine needs unlimited memory and time, both is not available to any physical thing.

Comment: Another minimalist example for a Turing complete language is [Brainfuck](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brainfuck), which syntax consists of 8 symbols.

Comment: @sebhofer which [we've also shown](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1563/52) that Mathematica can act as an interpreter for. :)

Comment: @rcollyer that's quite cool! I wasn't aware of it.

Answer (score 24):

Something is turing complete if you can simulate a turing machine with it.

http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/TuringMachine.html

There's one just sitting there in the documentation.

Comment: Well, to be universal you must be able to simulate any turing machine, not just "a turing machine"? Is it so obvious that you can specify all machines with that functions input? I.e. is it clear that the input for the function is defined in a way equivalent to a turing complete grammar?

Comment: I apologize. My syntax here wasn't sharp. Given a Turing machine, you can simulate that Turing machine using the TuringMachine function.