# Generating a Sierpinski carpet

Tags: programming, function-construction, generative-art, fractals

I am trying to draw a [Sierpinski_carpet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sierpinski_carpet). I have code that works, but I think there is a more elegant way to do than my way. Maybe I couls use `Tuples` or `Permutations` or some similar function to simplify my code.

[image]

```
f[{{x1_, y1_}, {x2_, y2_}}] := Map[Mean, {
    {{{x1, x1, x1}, {y1, y1, y1}}, {{x1, x1, x2}, {y1, y1, y2}}},
    {{{x1, x1, x1}, {y1, y1, y2}}, {{x1, x1, x2}, {y1, y2, y2}}},
    {{{x1, x1, x1}, {y1, y2, y2}}, {{x1, x1, x2}, {y2, y2, y2}}},
    {{{x1, x1, x2}, {y1, y1, y1}}, {{x1, x2, x2}, {y1, y1, y2}}},
    {{{x1, x1, x2}, {y1, y2, y2}}, {{x1, x2, x2}, {y2, y2, y2}}},
    {{{x1, x2, x2}, {y1, y1, y1}}, {{x2, x2, x2}, {y1, y1, y2}}},
    {{{x1, x2, x2}, {y1, y1, y2}}, {{x2, x2, x2}, {y1, y2, y2}}},
    {{{x1, x2, x2}, {y1, y2, y2}}, {{x2, x2, x2}, {y2, y2, y2}}}
    }, {3}];
d = Nest[Join @@ f /@ # &, {{{0., 0.}, {1, 1}}}, 3];
Graphics[Rectangle @@@ d]
Clear["`*"]
```

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Version 11.1 introduces [`MengerMesh`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MengerMesh.html):

```
MengerMesh[3]
```

[image]

[image]

---

---

This seems the most natural to me:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
carpet[n_] := Nest[ArrayFlatten[{{#, #, #}, {#, 0, #}, {#, #, #}}] &, 1, n]

ArrayPlot[carpet @ 5, PixelConstrained -> 1]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Shorter (in InputForm), but perhaps harder to read and slightly slower, though speed hardly matters given the geometric memory usage:

```
carpet[n_] := Nest[ArrayFlatten @ ArrayPad[{{0}}, 1, {{#}}] &, 1, n]
```

---

### Style by level

With a minor change we can increment the values with each fractal level allowing identification such as styling, or other processing.

Wild colors are but a few commands away:

```
carpet2[n_] := Nest[ArrayFlatten[{{#, #, #}, {#, 0, #}, {#, #, #}}] &[1 + #] &, 1, n]

Table[
  ArrayPlot[carpet2 @ 4, PixelConstrained -> 1, ColorFunction -> color],
  {color, ColorData["Gradients"]}
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

### Extension to three dimensions

A Menger sponge courtesy of chyanog, with refinements:

```
carpet3D[n_] :=
   With[{m = # (1 - CrossMatrix[{1,1,1}])}, Nest[ArrayFlatten[m, 3] &, 1, n]]

Image3D[ carpet3D[4] ]
```

[image]

---

### Element coordinates

If you wish to get coordinates for display with graphics primitives or analysis this can be done efficiently using `SparseArray` Properties:

```
coords = SparseArray[#]["NonzeroPositions"] &;
```

Example usages:

```
Graphics @ Point @ coords @ carpet @ 4
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Graphics3D[Cuboid /@ coords @ carpet3D @ 3]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: As a newbie MMA user, I agree this seems most natural. +1

Comment: @RunnyKine Thanks! :-)

Comment: The quilt is pretty.

Comment: +1 for having taught me `PixelConstrained -> 1` and for the beautiful images.

Comment: Very nice! 3D version,`carpet[n_] := 
 Nest[ArrayFlatten[{{{#, #, #}, {#, 0, #}, {#, #, #}}, {{#, 0, #}, {0,
        0, 0}, {#, 0, #}}, {{#, #, #}, {#, 0, #}, {#, #, #}}}, 3] &, 
  1, n]; Image3D[carpet[3]]`

Comment: +1 not sure how i missed this one. love the graphics - added to my Pinterest HOF http://pinterest.com/pin/282389839107715883/

Comment: @Vitaliy Thank you.

Comment: Looks so awesome...+1 man!

Comment: @Phonon Thank you.

Comment: how do you know about v11.1? I can't find anywhere news about its release

Comment: @glS Someone linked to http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/SummaryOfNewFeaturesIn111.html and checking https://develop.open.wolframcloud.com/app/view/newNotebook I found that it is live on Open Cloud.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard has version 11.1 been released?

Comment: @ubpdqn It is not on http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/quick-revision-history.html yet but as noted above Open Cloud is now running 11.1.  I haven't attempted to upgrade so I don't know if it is actually available for download yet.

Answer (score 24):

Assuming you want a vector-based image, it's more efficient to cut holes:

```
translations = {#, #} & /@ Complement[Tuples[{-1, 0, 1}, 2], {{0, 0}}];
shrink[{{x0_, y0_}, {x1_, y1_}}] := {{2 x0 + x1, 2 y0 + y1}, {x0 + 2 x1, y0 + 2 y1}}/3
children[sq : {{x0_, y0_}, {x1_, y1_}}] := 
  With[{side = x1 - x0, newsq = shrink[sq]},
    (newsq + #) & /@ (side translations)]
gen = NestList[Join @@ children /@ # &, {{{1, 1}, {2, 2}}/3}, 3];
Graphics[Rectangle @@@ Join @@ gen]
```

For the same generation you need to draw $1/8$ of the rectangles.

```
ngen = 4;
gen = NestList[Join @@ children /@ # &, {{{1, 1}, {2, 2}}/3}, ngen];
colors = Table[Blend[{RGBColor[0.5, 0.5, 1], White}, i/ngen], {i, 0, ngen}];
Graphics[{Black, Rectangle[{0, 0}, {1, 1}], White, Rectangle @@@ Join @@ gen}]
Graphics[{Red, Rectangle[{0, 0}, {1, 1}], MapThread[Prepend, {Apply[Rectangle, gen, {2}], colors}]}]
```

[image: Sierpinski 2D]

Here is the 3D version:

```
rule = 0 -> CrossMatrix[{1, 1, 1}];
Graphics3D[Cuboid /@ Position[Nest[ArrayFlatten[# /. rule, 3] &, 0, 3], 0]]
```

[image: Sierpinski 3D]

Answer (score 18):

Here are two methods using rules, shamelessly modified from a MathGroup posting (http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2007/May/msg01356.html).

```
rules = # -> ArrayPad[{{0}}, 1, #] & /@ {0, 1}
f1[m_] := ArrayFlatten[m /. rules]
drawSerp[n_] := ArrayPlot[Nest[f1, 1, n], Frame -> False]
drawSerp[3]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

An alternative cute ASCII implementation, borrowed from http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Sierpinski_carpet#Mathematica

```
n = 3;
Grid[Nest[ArrayFlatten[# /. rules] &, {{1}}, 
   n] //. {0 -> " ", 1 -> "#"}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Shamelessly upvoting.

Comment: +1 Using `ArrayPlot` instead of `ColorNegate@Image` in the first solution gives a crisper rendering (and happens to be about 50% faster, too).

Answer (score 18):

After an initial attempt with a `Graphics`-based solution, it became apparent that raster-based solutions would be far more efficient.  Methods based on `ArrayPlot` work nicely, but I wondered whether image-based manipulations might be the most efficient possible way, given that they would be optimized for precisely the kinds of operations being performed here.

Indeed, **the following is an order of magnitude faster than anything I have timed yet,** while sharing the expressive clarity of several other answers that have already appeared. Another advantage is that it scales the output resolution to match the depth of the approximation to the carpet.

```
carpet[n_, white_: 1, black_: 0] := 
 Nest[{ImageAssemble[{{#1, #1, #1}, {#1, #2, #1}, {#1, #1, #1}}], 
       ImageResize[#2, 3 First[ImageDimensions[#2]]]} & @@ # &, 
   Image /@ {{{black}}, {{white}}}, n] // First
```

It literally pieces all the pixels together, starting with a black pixel (`Image[{{black}}]`) and a white pixel (`Image[{{white}}]`)--whose colors you may optionally specify as arguments--reassembling them at each stage in the familiar three by three pattern (`ImageAssemble`) and, preparatory to the next stage, rescaling the central white pixel to match the size (`ImageResize`).  (At the end it throws away the upscaled white image.)  Here is `carpet[7]`, a $2187$ by $2187$ image ($0.05$ seconds):

[image: Carpet]

It is an easy exercise to modify this to start with any central image (the "focus") instead of just a white pixel.  Under prompting by Mr.Wizard (see comments), I offer the sharpest possible solution.  To create it, you need to begin with an image whose dimensions are a power of three and downsize it all the way to one pixel, creating a list of images that will serve as the foci of interest:

```
i = ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Lena"}];             (* Original image *)
n = 3^(k = Floor[Log[3, Min[ImageDimensions[i]]]]); (* Nearest lower power of 3 *)
focus = ImageResize[ImageCrop[i, {n, n}] // ImageAdjust, n/3^#] & /@ Range[k, 0, -1]
```

**An attractive Sierpinski carpet is now particularly simple to make.**  Here is a general implementation with a default black background

```
carpet[focus_List, background_: Image[{{0}}]] := 
  Fold[ImageAssemble[{{#1, #1, #1}, {#1, #2, #1}, {#1, #1, #1}}] &, background, focus];
```

and here is an application to the test image:

```
carpet[focus]
```

[image: Lena's carpet]

Because this process is so fast, in less than one second we can make carpets of all the example data (assuming they have already been downloaded):

```
carpet[ExampleData[#], Image[{{1}}]] & /@ ExampleData["TestImage"]
```

[image: Quilt of carpets]

Comment: What's the code to make either of the images in your output?  (I think I could figure it out but I'm suggesting that you include it.)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I gave the code for the first one :-).

Comment: Thanks.  v7 users FYI: you'll need `black = ColorConvert[black, "RGB"]`

Comment: I observe that this isn't producing pixel-accurate images; perhaps you could calculate the image size necessary and use a different resize algorithm to avoid the blurring.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I do apply a little sleight of hand in first tripling the size of `white` and then letting it get downscaled to the central image; a tiny bit of resolution is lost there (there are slight changes around edges of features). After that, I cannot fathom what you might mean by "pixel-accurate," given that the original `black` and `white` images *must* be scaled down. However, you are correct that one can control the final appearance; *e.g.*, the option `, Resampling -> "Lanczos"` in `ImageAssemble` sharpens the result.

Comment: I meant that the smallest "holes" are not sharp 1x1 pixel blocks but rather blurry blobs, when zoomed in.  I suppose that could be a v7 problem (or my own), but anyway, it will have to wait until later as I'm off for a while.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard They *have* to be blurry: they are, after all, $1\times 1$ renderings of the original $116\times 116$ images! If you want to zoom in like that, then just apply my first solution, beginning with the desired images in place of the one-pixel starting images. (But don't get too aggressive--*MMA* eats RAM like crazy when trying to do this.) If you want a really beautiful image, then a hybrid of the two approaches may be the way to go: build up, say, a three-level carpet by sizing up, then build *down* (via the first solution) starting with that carpet as the "black" image.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard To achieve a really sharp solution, we need to crop the central image to dimensions which are powers of three.  I have modified my answer to show this technique. Thank you for your suggestions!

Answer (score 11):

One lame method would be to create a replacement rule which replaces one `Rectangle`'s of an graphics which the appropriate 8 others.

```
f[p_, {min_, max_}] := p/3 max + (1 - p/3) min;
rule = Rectangle[{xmin_, ymin_}, {xmax_, ymax_}] -> 
   With[{expr = Table[If[i =!= 1 || j =!= 1, 
     Rectangle[{f[i, xmin, xmax], f[j, ymin, ymax]}, 
               {f[i + 1, xmin, xmax], f[j + 1, ymin, ymax]}], {}], 
   {j, 0, 2}, {i, 0, 2}]}, Flatten[(expr &)[min, max]]];
```

Then a simple `Nest` with one initial rectangle does the job.

```
Graphics[Nest[# /. rule &, Rectangle[{-1., -1.}, {1., 1.}], 4]]
```

I spare another black and white image here, because a more beautiful thing can be created when you use the iterative style function which can be found on the [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sierpinski_carpet), compile it and *save the number of iterations*

```
fillCarpet = Compile[{{pixel, _Integer, 1}},
  Module[{x = pixel[[1]], y = pixel[[2]], result = 1, iter = 0},
   While[x > 0 || y > 0,
    If[Mod[x, 3] === 1 && Mod[y, 3] === 1, result = 0; Break[]];
    x = Quotient[x, 3];
    y = Quotient[y, 3];
    ++iter;
    ];
   {result, iter}
   ], CompilationTarget -> "C", Parallelization -> True, 
  RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}]

Image@fillCarpet[Table[{i, j}, {j, 0, 3^6-1}, {i, 0, 3^6-1}]]
```

Here the self-similarity is highlighted through the iteration count. Now we can create various images which have sizes of `3^n-1` for different `n`

```
Show[Image@
    fillCarpet[Table[{i, j}, {j, 0, 3^# - 1}, {i, 0, 3^# - 1}]], 
   ImageSize -> 256] & /@ Range[3, 5]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]
[image: Mathematica graphics]
[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 8):

Many of the approaches here use image processing functions and they are blazing fast and very cool.  However, there are advantages of a primitives based approach.  When studying fractals, sometimes you need vertex information of the approximations, for example.  Also, I don't think these image based techniques extend easily to self-similar sets that are not based on a rectangular decomposition.  So, here's a reasonably fast approach using graphics primitives.

```
Clear[step];
step = With[{shifts = N@{
       {0, 0}, {1/3, 0}, {2/3, 0},
       {0, 1/3},                {2/3, 1/3},
       {0, 2/3}, {1/3, 2/3}, {2/3, 2/3}
       }},
   Compile[{{vertices, _Real, 2}},
    Module[{vv},
     vv = vertices/3;
     Table[pt + # & /@ vv, {pt, shifts}]
     ], CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable},
    Parallelization -> True
    ]
   ];

depth = 7;
init = N[{
    {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}
    }];
t = AbsoluteTime[];
polygons = Flatten[Nest[step, init, depth], depth]; // AbsoluteTiming
Graphics[Polygon[polygons]]

(* Out: {0.746998, Null} *)

(* Repetitive Sierpinski picture omitted.

(* Put in a new cell and execute all at once for reliable timing. *)
AbsoluteTime[] - t

(* Out: 4.559120 *)
```

About 10 times slower than whuber's `carpet` command.  Of course, this can never be as fast as the image based stuff, which is manipulated at a lower level.

Comment: +1 Once you head down this road to generalization, you might as well implement an [IFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterated_function_system).

Comment: @whuber Almost - have you seen the packages on my Mathematica page: http://facstaff.unca.edu/mcmcclur/Mathematica.html  These include not just image generation code but code to compute Laplacians on self-similar sets and code to compute the dimensions of self-similar sets of finite type, where the open set condition is not satisfied.

Comment: @whuber or an L-system. I considered adapting my [bf parser](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1599/52) to do just that.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks for @Mark McClure. Inspired by him, my original code is simplified.

This seems also natural.

[image]

```
f[v_] := Table[i + j, {i, Drop[Tuples[{0, 1, 2}, 2], {5}]}, {j, v}]/3.;
d = Nest[Join @@ f /@ # &, N@{{{0, 0}, {1, 1}}}, 3];
Graphics[Rectangle @@@ d]
```

[image]

It's also easily generalized to 3D:

```
f[v_] := Table[ i + j, {i, Select[Tuples[{0, 1, 2}, 3], Count[#, 1] < 2 &]},
  {j, v}]/3.;
d = Nest[Join @@ f /@ # &, N@{{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1}}}, 3];
Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[], Cuboid /@ d}, Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

Comment: Please see the most recent section of my answer.  I believe if you run `Timing`s you will find it is superior.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I'm impressed.

Comment: @chyanog There seems to be an error in the second piece of code (version 12.1).

Answer (score 3):

I might as well... as a variation, here's a [chaos game](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ChaosGame.html) method for generating the carpet:

```
With[{verts = DeleteCases[Tuples[{-1, 0, 1}, {2}], {0, 0}], n = 1*^6},
   Graphics[{AbsolutePointSize[1/2],
             Point[NestList[(2 RandomChoice[verts] + #)/3 &, RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 2], n]]}]]
```

[image: chaos game carpet]

Comment: Now, the carpet is drawn...and it would be also good for us (mathematicians, or physicists) to obtain the corresponding adj.matrix. However, this can be possible if one makes the program think that the drawn object is a graph. Is there any intelligent way to do this? Sorry, if I am posting too stupid comment...Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Not with this procedure, due to the stochastic nature of the method used.

Answer (score 2):

This is more or less equivalent to halirutan's approach, but slightly compacted (adapted from code I wrote ~ 10 years ago, before `Tuples[]` came along):

```
Block[{n = 5, pos = Select[Tuples[2 {-1, 0, 1}/3, {2}], (Count[#, 0] < 2) &]},
      Graphics[Nest[Function[g, (g /. v_ /; VectorQ[v, NumericQ] :> v/3 - #) & /@ pos],
                    Rectangle[{-1, -1}, {1, 1}], n]]]
```

[image: the carpet]

The sponge version:

```
Block[{n = 4, pos = Select[Tuples[2 {-1, 0, 1}/3, {3}], (Count[#, 0] < 2) &]}, 
    Graphics3D[{Directive[EdgeForm[], GrayLevel[1/5], Glow[Gray], Specularity[1/2, 100]], 
                Nest[Function[g3d, (g3d /. v_ /; VectorQ[v, NumericQ] :> v/3 - #) & /@ pos],
                     Cuboid[{-1, -1, -1}, {1, 1, 1}], n]}, Boxed -> False]]
```

[image: the sponge]

A sponge with "less faded" coloring:

```
Block[{n = 4, pos = Select[Tuples[2 {-1, 0, 1}/3, {3}], (Count[#, 0] < 2) &]}, 
   Graphics3D[{Directive[EdgeForm[], ColorData["Legacy", "DodgerBlue"], 
                         Specularity[3/4, 20]], 
               Nest[Function[g3d, (g3d /. v_ /; VectorQ[v, NumericQ] :> v/3 - #) & /@ pos], 
                    Cuboid[{-1, -1, -1}, {1, 1, 1}], n]},
              Boxed -> False, Lighting -> "Neutral"]]
```

[image: blue sponge]

Comment: In your picture the sponge looks faded, and on my system it renders as a solid gray cube.

Comment: The faded-ness was more or less deliberate; the coloring directives can be changed if needed. I'll render something differently colored if needed. The "solid gray" was unintentional; it seems I copied a wrong cell from my old notebook. See it now.

Comment: Okay.  Both functions (yours and mine) take a long time *render* at `n = 4` but this 3D code takes 1.4 seconds to merely evaluate while mine takes 0.05 second.  Likewise your 2D code takes 0.2558 second whereas mine takes 0.0005 second.  In what situation will these methods be preferred?

Comment: @Mr. Wizard, well, it's *old* code. :) Except for the `Tuples[]`, and `Glow[]`/`Specularity[]`, everything there was more or less how it was when I wrote it in version 4 (e.g. the original code used `SurfaceColor[]`, and I had rolled my own version of `Tuples[]` before). I also figured that seeing another replacement-rule based implementation might prove instructive.

Answer (score 2):

Wolfram finally (V10.2) has made a function [`SubstitutionSystem`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SubstitutionSystem.html) that does the job. These are examples from documentation (see Applications part).

```
ArrayPlot[
 SubstitutionSystem[{1 -> {{1, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 1}}, 
 0 -> ConstantArray[0, {3, 3}]}, {{1}}, 5][[-1]]]
```

[image]

And using @Mr.Wizard notation with `CrossMatrix` from the answer above:

```
Image3D[
   SubstitutionSystem[{1 -> 1 - CrossMatrix[{1, 1, 1}], 
   0 -> ConstantArray[0, {3, 3, 3}]}, {{{1}}}, {3}][[1]]]
```

[image]