# Sierpinski carpet with GraphData

Tags: graphs-and-networks, combinatorics, fractals

Is this graph in the list among the so-called "standard" structures used in `GraphData`? However, I have not found yet anything like "Carpet" or "Sponge" in the list of the objects that can be built. Maybe, this graph has a different name?

For me, using `GraphData` helps to save time for constructing adjacency matrix; therefore, I would rather prefer using this function than drawing the graph...

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/22052/generating-a-sierpinski-carpet)?

Answer (score 18):

I don't think there is a carpet graph built-in, but it's hard to be sure that something is *not* there.  Still it's not hard to construct a `Graph` -- not quite the same thing as drawing it (I wasn't sure what you meant).

There are probably more efficient ways, but adapting [Mr.Wizard](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/121)'s [`carpet` function](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/22052/generating-a-sierpinski-carpet/22058#22058), it is fairly straightforward to make an edge between adjacent `1`s in the matrix.

```
carpet[n_] := (* Mr.Wizard *)
  Nest[ArrayFlatten[{{#, #, #}, {#, 0, #}, {#, #, #}}] &, 1, n];
carpetGraph[n_] := Module[{sa, edges, parts, onesPositions},
  parts = {{1, 0}, {0, 1}};
  sa = SparseArray@carpet[n];
  onesPositions = sa["NonzeroPositions"];
  edges = Flatten[
    With[{m = ArrayPad[sa, 1]}, 
     Function[pos,  pos -> # & /@
        Pick[pos + # & /@ parts, Extract[m, 1 + pos + # & /@ parts], 1]] /@
      onesPositions],
    1];
  Graph[onesPositions, edges, VertexCoordinates -> onesPositions, DirectedEdges -> False]
  ]

g = carpetGraph[4]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You can then compute the adjacency matrix as with any other graph:

```
(* AdjacencyMatrix[g] // Timing // First *)
(* {0.010865, SparseArray[<12848>, {4096, 4096}]} *)

AdjacencyMatrix[carpetGraph[5]] // Timing
(* {0.878410, SparseArray[<104080>, {32768, 32768}]} *)
```

Comment: Michael, I can't run your code because v7 doesn't have `Graph` but I see that you modified `carpet`; I'm not sure why.  It seems slower than using my original code and converting to a sparse array at the end.  I suggest you try this code with my original and then `sa = SparseArray @ carpet[n];`.  Also, you seem to be using `sa["NonzeroPositions"]` three separate times; why not assign that to an extra Symbol in the Module?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Thanks for the suggestions.  I started with the idea of `SparseArray` and didn't think of applying it at the end.  I suppose I could do something about `pos + # & /@ parts` appearing twice, too.  I'm not sure it's worth changing, although the three `sa["NonzeroPositions"]` seem worth an extra variable.  It turns out that the speed is not affected noticeably.  (I get roughly equal timings, both faster and slower, up to `carpetGraph[6]`.)  My mem. usage would go up 20GB on `carpetGraph[5]` earlier but not now.  Must have been something *Mma* ate. :)

Answer (score 13):

Here is a "general" [Lindenmayer System](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L-system) generator I wrote [in the spirit of code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/9351/315). Please beware that the objective of code-golfing is writing  the shorter possible program to fulfill an objective, disregarding good practices, robustness, etc. Stay safe and don't use this style in real life.

```
f[i_, b_, h_, j_, r_, n_] := 
  (a = h; p = j; s = k = {}; t = Flatten;
  (Switch[#,
      6, s = {a, p, s},
      8, {a, p, s} = s,
      _C, k = {k, Black, Line@{p, p += {Cos@a, Sin@a}}},
      _W, k = {k, White, Line@{p, p += {Cos@a, Sin@a}}}];
     If[# < 9, a += I^# b]) & /@ t@Nest[# /. r &, i, n];
  Graphics@t@k)
```

Where

> i : Initial state;
> b : rotation angle
> h : initial angle
> j : initial position
> r : production rules
> n : iterations

And the production rules for the grammar are:

> 2 = Turn Left (-);
> 4 = Turn Right (+);
> 6 = Push and Turn Left ("[");
> 8 = Pop and Turn Right ("]");
> C[i] = Draw (Any number of symbols)
> W[i] = Draw in White (Any number of symbols)
> Any other symbol = Do Nothing, just use it in producing next state

So [the rules for the carpet](http://ecademy.agnesscott.edu/%7Elriddle/ifs/carpet/carpet.htm) are:

```
f[{C[1]}, Pi/2, 0, {0, 0}, 
  {C@1 -> {C@1, 4, C@1, 2, C@1, 2, C@1, 2, W@3, 4, C@1, 4, C@1, 4, C@1, 2, C@1}, 
   W@3 -> {W@3, W@3, W@3}}, 5]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Other usage examples (sorry, couldn't resist)

Examples:

```
f[{C@1, X}, Pi/2, 0, {0, 0}, {X -> {X, 4, Y, C@1}, Y -> {C@1, X, 2, Y}}, 10]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
f[{C@1}, Pi/2, 0, {0,0}, {C@1->{C@1, 2, C@1, 4, C@1, 4, C@1, 2, C@1}}, 6]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
f[{C@1}, Pi/4, Pi/2, {0, 0}, {C@2 -> {C@2, C@2}, C@1 -> {C@2, 6, C@1, 8, C@1}}, 10]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
f[{C[1]}, Pi/3, 0, {0, 0}, 
  {C@1 -> {C@2, 4, C@1, 4, C@2}, C@2 -> {C@1, 2, C@2, 2, C@1}}, 10]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
f[{X},5/36 Pi, Pi/3, {0,0},
 {X->{C@1, 4, 6, 6, X, 8, 2, X, 8, 2, C@1, 6, 2, C@1, X, 8, 4, X}, 
 C@1->{C@1, C@1}}, 6]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Edit**

Since you wanted a `Graph` ... here it is:

```
f[i_, b_, h_, j_, r_, n_] := (a = h; p = j; s = k = {}; g =.;
   t = Flatten;
   (Switch[#,
       6, s = {a, p, s},
       8, {a, p, s} = s,
       _C, AppendTo[k, {p, (p += {Cos@a, Sin@a})}],
       _W, p += {Cos@a, Sin@a}];
      If[# < 9, a += I^# b]) & /@ t@Nest[# /. r &, i, n];);
f[{C[1]}, Pi/2, 0, {0, 0}, 
   {C@1 -> {C@1, 4, C@1, 2, C@1, 2, C@1, 2, W@3, 4, C@1, 4, C@1, 4, C@1, 2, C@1}, 
    W@3 -> {W@3, W@3, W@3}}, 2];

g = Graph[Rule @@@ k];
(PropertyValue[{g, #}, VertexCoordinates] = #) & /@ VertexList@g;
g
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If you let Mathematica to place the Vertices automagically, you also get nice pictures

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: That sure *looks* nice, but since this isn't Code Golf you should probably localize your variables.  Also, how long is this supposed to take to render?  I tried the first example before starting to write this comment, and it's still running.  (Okay, it just finished. +1)

Comment: Well I just lifted my vote.  This is undoubtedly cool but I don't think it answers the question, which I think is about `Graph` data as Michael's answer produces.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Now it does Graphs :)

Comment: Noted and vote restored.  Please consider adding `Module` still; it's just bad practice not to, outside of Code Golf.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I understand your feelings. This solution hasn't any virtue but brevity.

Comment: "I cannot agree with those who rank modesty among the virtues." Sherlock Holmes :)

Answer (score 7):

As of version 11, this is built in:

```
GraphData["SierpinskiCarpet"]
(* {{"Cycle", 8}, {"SierpinskiCarpet", 2}, {"SierpinskiCarpet", 3}, {"SierpinskiCarpet", 4}} *)

GraphData /@ %
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

The latest version of [IGraph/M](http://szhorvat.net/mathematica/IGraphM) incorporates [Henrik Schumacher's mesh/graph conversion functions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/160457/12).  This way we can easily obtain the face-adjacency graph of a [`MengerMesh`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MengerMesh.html), and add the appropriate vertex coordinates.

```
Needs["IGraphM`"]

With[{mesh = MengerMesh[4]},
 IGMeshCellAdjacencyGraph[mesh, 2,
  VertexCoordinates -> PropertyValue[{mesh, {2, All}}, MeshCellCentroid]
 ]
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

How about a 3D one?

```
With[{mesh = MengerMesh[2, 3]},
 IGMeshCellAdjacencyGraph[mesh, 3,
  VertexCoordinates -> PropertyValue[{mesh, {3, All}}, MeshCellCentroid]
 ]
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

What if we want a Sierpinski graph?  The mesh looks like this:

```
mesh = SierpinskiMesh[3]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This time each face (shaded triangle) will correspond to a graph node, and two triangles are connected if they share a vertex.  We construct the face-vertex incidence matrix `bm`. To obtain our graph's adjacency matrix, we need those elements of `bm.Transpose[bm]` which are `1`. We enlist the help of the [BoolEval package](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/2822/12) for this.

```
bm = IGMeshCellAdjacencyMatrix[mesh, 2 (* face, i.e. 2D *), 0 (* vertex, i.e. 0D *)];

Needs["BoolEval`"]

AdjacencyGraph[
 BoolEval[bm.Transpose[bm] == 1],
 VertexCoordinates -> PropertyValue[{mesh, {2, All}}, MeshCellCentroid]
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Since we are in `11.1`,why not use `MengerMesh`?

Comment: @yode See my comment on Chip's answer.

Comment: @yode I added a solution using MengerMesh now.

Answer (score 3):

If we are in `11.1`, we can use in-built function `MengerMesh`.Well,I always faced a problem about grid layout.Whatever it is simple enough to plot *Sierpinski*

```
AdjacencyGraph[Graphics`Region`ToMeshObject[MengerMesh[4]]["AdjacencyMatrix"]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

## Update

I have found a properties of mesh object `"VertexCoordinateRules"`.It is can serve a good grid layout for this case.

```
mesh = Graphics`Region`ToMeshObject[MengerMesh[4]];
g = AdjacencyGraph[mesh["AdjacencyMatrix"]];
Graph[g, VertexCoordinates -> mesh["VertexCoordinateRules"]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Of course we can change the `MengerMesh` into `SierpinskiMesh` or `CantorMesh`,then we can get

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 2):

The mesh-related functionality in current versions allows for relatively compact code for generating the graph version of the Sierpinski carpet. The following solution is more or less similar to [this previous answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/121848):

```
pos = DeleteCases[Tuples[2 {-1, 0, 1}/3, {2}], {0, 0}];

With[{n = 5},
     sqrs = Flatten[Nest[# /. Rectangle[p1_, p2_] :>
                         Map[Rectangle[p1/3 - #, p2/3 - #] &, pos] &,
                         Rectangle[-{1, 1}, {1, 1}], n]];
     pts = Flatten[Tuples[Transpose[{##}]][[{1, 2, 4, 3}]] & @@@ sqrs, 1];
     mr = MeshRegion[pts, Polygon[Partition[Range[Length[pts]], 4]]];
     Graph[Range[MeshCellCount[mr, 0]], UndirectedEdge @@@ (First /@ MeshCells[mr, 1]), 
           EdgeShapeFunction -> "Line", VertexCoordinates -> MeshCoordinates[mr],
           VertexSize -> Small]]
```

[image: Sierpinski carpet graph]

---

The code for the Menger sponge's graph version is similarly compact:

```
pos = Select[Tuples[2 {-1, 0, 1}/3, {3}], (Count[#, 0] < 2) &];

With[{n = 3},
     cubs = Flatten[Nest[# /. Cuboid[p1_, p2_] :>
                         Map[Cuboid[p1/3 - #, p2/3 - #] &, pos] &, 
                         Cuboid[-{1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}], n]];
     pts = Flatten[Tuples[Transpose[{##}]][[{1, 5, 7, 3, 2, 6, 8, 4}]] & @@@ cubs, 1];
     mr = BoundaryMesh[MeshRegion[pts, Hexahedron /@ Partition[Range[Length[pts]], 8]]];
     Graph3D[Range[MeshCellCount[mr, 0]], UndirectedEdge @@@ (First /@ MeshCells[mr, 1]), 
             EdgeShapeFunction -> "Line", VertexCoordinates -> MeshCoordinates[mr],
             VertexSize -> Small]]
```

[image: Menger sponge graph]

Answer (score 2):

Since V 11.1 we have [MengerMesh](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MengerMesh.html)

```
MengerMesh[3]
```

[image]

```
MengerMesh[3, 3]
```

[image]

Other iterated maps include `SierpinskiMesh`, `CantorMesh` and
`ArrayMesh`. A full listing is here:

[Iterated Maps & Fractals](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/IteratedMapsAndFractals.html)

Just for fun:

```
k = 12;

r = #2 /. {x__Real} :> .1 {{7, -#}, {#, 7}} . {x} + y &;

f[n_] := {f @ 1 = N @ Polygon @ {y = {0, .7^k}, 0 y, x = {.002, 0}, x + y}, r[-4, p = f[n - 1]], 4~r~p}

Graphics @ f @ k
```

[image]

Source: [Create a fractal tree](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/18785/create-a-fractal-tree)

Answer (score 1):

Version 12.1 now has the function [`MeshConnectivityGraph[]`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MeshConnectivityGraph.html) which can be used on `MengerMesh[]`:

```
MeshConnectivityGraph[MengerMesh[4, 2], PlotTheme -> "LargeNetworkDefault"]
```

[image: Sierpinski carpet graph]

```
MeshConnectivityGraph[MengerMesh[2, 3], PlotTheme -> "LargeNetworkDefault"]
```

[image: Menger sponge graph]